# Its possible detect if the user use pwa in django backend

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps, django-request

in javascript it is possible to check something like: `(window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) || (window.navigator.standalone) || document.referrer.includes('android-app://')`
will return true if using pwa/twa, but I need to check the Django backend for security reasons

Comment: You can make an ajax request to the server if the user were using pwa

Answer (score 0):

Django runs on the server while that particular JavaScript runs on the client. You could have the client make a request and tell the server that this particular session is using a PWA, but Django can't determine it.